# MvvmCross file plugin still required?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvmcross, .net-standard

Regarding the [file plugin](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmCross.Plugin.File/) (OS independent file system access) for `MvvmCross`:

- Do I understand correctly that this plugin was created at a time when file system access wasn't yet possible using [.NET standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/files/)?
- Meaning for new projects there's no reason to use the file plugin and I can use .NET standard without any drawbacks?

Comment: Not necessary at all. It will probably be removed in the future too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MvvmCross.Plugins.File plugin was created back when we had Portable class libraries and didn't have any profile that had any `System.File.IO` namespaces available to us.

So with the introduction with .NET Standard, most of what it does has become obsolete. So you are right to say that for new projects, you could get away without having to use this plugin at all, because all of the API is available to you in .NET Standard.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I understand correctly that this plugin was created at a time when file system access wasn't yet possible using .NET standard?

No, MvvmCross is a cross-platform MVVM framework.

**Among the features MvvmCross provides are:**

- ViewModel to View bindings using own customizable binding engine,
  which allows you to create own binding definitions for own custom
  views
- ViewModel to ViewModel navigation, helps you share behavior on
  how and when to navigate
- Inversion of Control through Dependency
  Injection and Property Injection
- Plugin framework, which lets you
  plug-in cool stuff like GPS Location, Localization, Sensors, Binding
  Extensions and a huge selection of 3rd party community plug-ins

For more details, you could refer to the link. https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Samples

> Meaning for new projects there's no reason to use the file plugin and I can use .NET standard without any drawbacks?

Plugins have advantages for framework, but implementing direct in the UI projects is perfectly acceptable too.